# Как расширить модель джанги классом, с помощью композиции?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Предположим у меня есть модель:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    some_field = models.CharField()
```

Хочу её расширить функционалом класса:

```
class MyManager:
    def __init__(self, model: "MyModel"):
        self.model = model

    def print_some_field(self):
        print(self.model.some_field)
```

В итоге хочу получить:

```
my_model = MyModel.objects.create(some_field="asdf")
mo_model.my_manager.print_some_field()  # само использование менеджера
```

Как это лучше сделать? Куда добавлять, в `__init__` модели?

Comment: Не совсем понятен смысл класса MyManager, почему нельзя просто добавить метод print_some_field в класс модели или использовать данный класс как mixin (если предполагается расширение методами MyManager нескольких моделей)?

Comment: @Basalex, это же просто пример. Можно, конечно наследование использовать, но я хочу сделать композицией.

Comment: метод __ init __ у моделей не рекоммендуется трогать согласно документации следует использовать classmethod https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model